# Print rendered entity reference value

Tags: 7, theming, entities

How can I print the rendered values of an entity reference field into node.tpl.php?

I have an entity reference field called Instructors which references users.  Using Devel I can find the target_id of entity reference items, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to render these ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
// $node represents the node object
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$instructors = $wrapper->field_instructor->value();
```

Now in instructors you will have each instructor user object and you can print what ever information you want to print from it.

Comment: Since I'm using an entity reference field, would it be possible to use the method you suggest to render the final output as a link to the entity, or would I have to construct the link myself?

Comment: The above method is dependent on entity api which is required by the entity reference module. you can use a foreach loop on the instructors array and print the values.

Comment: Alright, after messing with it for a bit I finally came up with a solution.  Did need to use `foreach ($wrapper->field_instructor->value() as $i)` to get to property values.

Then created an array links from the uid and name properties and finally imploded the array for printing.

Took a bit of experimenting and trial and error on my part, but thanks for the tip off!